# The /src folder in eclipse is empty from a downloaded project

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded a Java project of my professor: on macOS, the `/src` folder contains the Java code, while on Windows it's empty, I don't understand why. How can I solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on `src/java` (second from above).

Comment: Yes I know. But on macOS it's not like that, I don't understand why

Comment: Have you pressed F5?

Comment: Yes, but nothing has changed

Comment: Do you need this directory?

Comment: I can also work on `src/java`, but I still doubt why no subfolder comes out in `/src`

Comment: Notice that the icons for 'src/java' is different from 'src'. The first one is showing a folder containing Java packages, the second is just a plain folder. Package explorer shows these two things separately. Are you using Package Explorer on both machines - or maybe one is Project Explorer? Both explorers have a number of options which control exactly how this is handled.